# Updating sub-properties via Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, relational-database, orm

I was wondering how to updated nested objects/sub-properties when using Entity Framework. But to make things clear, let's start with an example.

I have an object, which can own a number of other objects. In other words, an object which contains a list of a different type of objects. This could be a person, who has multiple cars.

```
public class PersonModel
{
    // ...
    public List<CarModel> Cars { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to make a service with a method called `AddCar()`, but I am a bit puzzled on what goes inside this method. It could look something like this:

```
public void AddCar(PersonModel owner, CarModel car)
{
    car.OwnerId = owner.Id;
    var ctx = GetDbContext();
    ctx.Cars.Add(car);
    ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

Obviously this is a bit simplified, but you get the point. The problem in the example above is that the owner does not get updated. The new car will not be added to `List<CarModel> Cars`, until the person is re-loaded from the database.

This must be a common issue, so I suppose there is some sort of standard way of dealing with this. I just have not been able to find it. Here are the different solutions I can think of:

- Make a method for updating the person from the database, which is called inside `AddCar()` (after adding the car).
- Alter the object `owner` by adding the car to the list of cars, on top of adding it to the database (also inside `AddCar()`).
- Add the new car to the list of cars inside `owner` and then make an update function which handles updating the owner, and all of its nested objects.

I cannot see any clear winnder in the suggestions above. Maybe it's something completely different? Any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is totally up to your design. If you want to use **Entity Framework AutoDetectChangesEnabled** feature, it can be track changes and store for you. This property default value is **true**.

```cs
public PersonModel Person()
{
   // navigation property virtual ICollection<T>
   public virtual ICollection<CarModel> Cars { get; set; }
}

public void AddCar(PersonModel owner, CarModel car)
{

    var ctx = GetDbContext();
    PersonModel person = ctx.person.GetPerson(owner.Id);
    // this is entity object and entity framework will track the changes.
    // so when you add a car to person, then you can call save changes method
    person.Cars.Add(car);
    ctx.SaveChanges();

    foreach(CarModel car in person.Cars.ToList())
    {
        // Id will not be empty.
        Console.WriteLine(car.Id);
    }
}
```

Otherwise, you need to manage it manually:

```cs
public void AddCar(PersonModel owner, CarModel car)
{
    car.OwnerId = owner.Id;
    var ctx = GetDbContext();
    ctx.Cars.Add(car);
    ctx.SaveChanges();
    owner.Cars.Add(car);
}
```

I assume `PersonModel` is reference type. So, this referenced type instance `owner` includes new car. You can reach it from where you call `AddCar` method.

**Note:** I changed your **Cars** property to [**Navigation Propery**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/relationships). This is the best way to manage model relations(also table relations). Look at also [**Lazy Loading**](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/lazyloading-in-entity-framework.aspx) with Entity  Framework.

Comment: What if the `owner` instance of `PersonModel` is not a direct reference to `DbContext`, but rather loaded and stored in a `List` (or similar) in some other class (e.g. a ViewModel)?

Comment: @Noceo if your PersonModel is ViewModel, you should manage everything with Entity Model and then map to ViewModel. Having relation(s) to Entity Model from View Model is really bad practice. ViewModel is for your view and  EntityModel is for your Data Access Layer and Business Logic Layer(up to your design) and these layers may not have a direct realtion to view and may not know each others. You can find more reason why you shouldn't create kind of realations.

Comment: I have a `ObservableCollection<PersonModel> Persons` in my ViewModel. It is populated by a method, which gets persons from the database (via EF) and inserts them into the collection. So from what I can tell, there is no link from the ViewModel to the data layer.

Comment: First, if you have kind of populate method, then you can call your CRUD operation from this method and can return collection from there by mapping EntityModel to ViewModel . Second, as I see, your `AddCar` method is DAL method. So, this method should not know anything about your view models. You should map your PersonModel(ViewModel) to proper EntityModel. Then, call `AddCar` method.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I think I might have an incorrect approach to Entity Framework altogether. I tend to have a ViewModel with its own collections which are then populated by refresh methods. This means being disconnected from the DbContext. And that is what is causing my problems. If you are supposed to link the ViewModel directly to the DbContext, that opens to some entirely different solutions. Like the one you show.

Comment: You should never use your EF entities outside of your data layer. Its bad practice. Instead let your queries project to DTO's. In a small project these DTOs can even be your actual view models.  I like CQS, command query seperation. The query handler can project from EF entities directly to its query result

Comment: @Noceo Beyond using of Entity Framework, you can separate your layer first. Then, you can consider which Entity Framework feature is good for your project and you can find the solution in my answer. Btw, if you think my answer answers your question well, then you can set as accepted answer. These days it is easy to forget :))